# How do I import a full color mesh into a scene in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

So I have my tango constructor created .obj file open in MeshLab and it looks great. Now I want to upload this colored image into my scene in Unity.  What are the specific import settings I need to have selected to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no export texture feature in current Tango Construtor.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will just have to get creative